# MySQL update column with value from a different table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following structure and example content. Table one has the membership_no set to the correct values, but table two has some incorrect values in the membership_no column. I am needing to query both tables and check to see when the membership_no values are not equal, then update table two's membership_no column with the value from table one.

Table One:

```
id     membership_no
====================
800960 800960
800965 800965
```

Table Two:

```
id     membership_no
====================
800960 800970
800965 800975
```

Update query so far. It is not catching all of the incorrect values from table two.

```
UPDATE
tabletwo
    INNER JOIN
    tableone ON tabletwo.id = tableone.id
SET 
    tabletwo.membership_no = tableone.membership_no;
```

**EDIT: Including SHOW CREATE and SELECT queries for unmatched membership_no column values.**

Table One SHOW:

```
CREATE TABLE `n2z7m3_kiduka_accounts_j15` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`membership_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
...
`membershipyear` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=800987 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table Two SHOW:

```
CREATE TABLE `n2z7m3_kiduka_accounts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`membership_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
...
`membershipyear` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=801072 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SELECT query for unmatched membership_no column values:

```
SELECT 
    u.name,
    a.membership_no as 'Joomla 1.5 accounts table', 
    j.membership_no as 'Joomla 3.0 accounts table' 
FROM 
    n2z7m3_kiduka_accounts_j15 AS a 
    INNER JOIN n2z7m3_users AS u ON a.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN n2z7m3_kiduka_accounts AS j ON a.user_id = j.membership_no 
    and a.membership_no != j.membership_no
ORDER BY u.name;
```

Comment: But, given that the ids and numbers are apparently always supposed to be the same, why do you need to compare the tables at all!?!?

Comment: It will catch all values appearing on both tables, doesn't matter if they are correct or not. You didn't filter anything.

Comment: If you can edit your question to show the results of the SQL queries: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tabletwo` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableone` this will be very useful .

Comment: @Martin I have updated my question to include the two SHOW CREATE TABLE queries and the SELECT query I was using to find unmatched membership_no column values. When I run your query, multiple records are changed, but if I run my SELECT query again, there are still mismatched membership_no values between the two tables.

Comment: thanks, I have updated my answser for you.

Comment: why are you showing us a select query?

Comment: @Martin I showed my SELECT query just in case there may be issues with how it is returning results when compared to the UPDATE query and the number of results affected by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Tim's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37989421/3536236) is perfectly valid, another variation is to add the filter qualifier to the `ON` clause such that:

```
UPDATE tabletwo
INNER JOIN
tableone ON tabletwo.id = tableone.id AND tabletwo.membership_no <> tableone.membership_no
SET 
tabletwo.membership_no = tableone.membership_no;
```

This means that you don't have the `WHERE` filter so it will process all rows, but will act on only those with differing `membership_no` values. Because it is an `INNER JOIN` the results will be both tables or no tables (Skipped/NULL result).

**EDIT:**

If you suspect you have a problem still, what does the MySQL command respond, do you have a specific error notice? With 80k columns, it may take a while for the comand to actually process , so are you giving the command time to complete or is PHP or the system causing the command to abort due to execution time expiry? (*Update your execution time on PHP and MySQL and rerun query just to see if that causes it to complete successfully?*)

**Suggestion**

As another sggestion I think your `UNIQUE KEY` should also be your AI key so for both tables:

```
DROP INDEX `user_id` ON <table> #removes the current unique index.
```

then

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id` ON <table> #addes unique index to the A_I column.
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE
    tabletwo
INNER JOIN
    tableone
    ON tabletwo.id = tableone.id
SET 
    tabletwo.membership_no = tableone.membership_no
WHERE tabletwo.membership_no <> tableone.membership_no
```

Comment: I suspect he have some kind of problem, even without that where clause it should have worked.

Comment: @sagi No, without the `WHERE` clause it would update _all_ joined records regardless of whether the membership numbers be equal or not.

Comment: OK, and? It will still update every membership number to the correct value!